# How does RDS decide whether to use burst or not?

Tags: amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS Mysql 8.0.16 instance: db.t3.micro, 200GB of gp2 storage. A script (Java 11, JDBC, single connection) populates the database with some dummy data. Pseudocode:

```
insert into TemplateClasses(...) values(...);
insert into TemplateStudents(...) values(...);

for (int _schoolId = 0; _schoolId < 20; ++_schoolId) {
  insert into Schools(id) values(_schoolId);
  insert into Classes(schoolId, ...) select _schoolId, ... from TemplateClasses;
  insert into Students(schoolId, ...) select _schoolId, ... from TemplateStudents;
}
```

I have 100% RDS burst balance and I start this script. The first few iterations usually consume 10-30% of the burst balance, but after it things get slow, and I see that burst balance is not being used (the script keeps running and there are no changes to the workload).

Here's a very typical picture:
[image: RDS]

What's the most probable cause of this behavior? How do I force RDS to spend 100% of the burst balance?

**Added on 1/9/2021**: I've changed the RDS instance type to db.t3.small and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. While this practically solves my problem, I'm still curious about the reason db.t3.micro behaves differently.

Comment: Is this related to RDS? If you spin up an EC2 instance of same class and run the test, are you getting same results?

Comment: @vasek I didn't try it. If you elaborate on how the results of this experiment may practically be useful, I'll consider trying it.